# Python driver for IBM DB2 does not work

Tags: python, db2

I try to execute a very simple sql statement that sets isolation level in DB2. I do it like so:

```
>>> import ibm_db
>>> cnx = ibm_db.connect("sample", "root", "root")
>>> sql = "CHANGE ISOLATION TO CS"
>>> query_stmt = ibm_db.prepare(cnx, sql)
>>> ibm_db.execute(query_stmt)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception
```

I also tried this:

```
>>> stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(cnx, sql)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception
```

The query for setting isolation level I took from [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001946.html) official tutorial. So, what's wrong with that and how can I fix it?

**EDIT**

I also tried other simple queries. And none of them works:

```
>>> ibm_db.exec_immediate(cnx, "LIST TABLES")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception
```

It seems like I lack some configuration, but I do not know how to check it and how to debug it. Need help.

**EDIT**

I tried this in `DB2 CLP`:

```
db2 => set schema sample
```

And got this error message:

> SQL1024N A database connection does not exist. SQLSTATE=08003

However, when I do this:

```
db2 => LIST DATABASE DIRECTORY
```

I get this:

```
...
database alias   SAMPLE
database name    SAMPLE
...
```

So, what the heck is going on? PS. I'm working on Windows 10, if it matters.

**EDIT**

Well, I managed to connect to sample database in command line and even listed all tables. However, I cannot do the same thing in Python. I even tried other simple queries like `select * from act` - in the console I get a number of rows, but in Python I still get this `Exception`.

**PROOF**

Here is a proof:

[image]

As you can see on the first screen, everything is ok. However, the same thing does not work in Python according to the second screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) First some dumb checks: is the DB server running and accepting connections. Have you checked if you are able to connect from command prompt sql tool and create tables and list tables.

2) Download the ibm_db driver source code from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ibm_db/ and it has some tests folder in it.
compare your connection settings with the config.py in the downloaded tests folder.

That's for resolving basic connectivity.

The official tutorial you quoted says "isolation changes are permitted using a type 2 connection, ". I am not sure if ibm_db is a type 2 driver or not. the README in the sources i just downloaded does not show anything related to the type of the driver.

regards
-Manas

Comment: It would be great, if you could elaborate a little bit on all this. For example, explain how to make some "dumb checks" etc. I'm new to DB2 and do not know all those commands to check that everything is set up ok.

Comment: please check db2 installation documentation. I never used db2.

Answer (score 0):

DB2 CLP commands are not SQL statements; they can only be interpreted by the CLP itself. Review the [SQL reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011049.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-6) for correct statement syntax. For example, to set the session isolation level you would use the statement `set current isolation cs`.

Comment: I also tried other sql commands like `select * from act`. In command line, this query returns data from a sample table, but in Python it does not work.